# How Backbone js interacts with css selectors?

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js

I just start learn around Backbone js. In a few minutes I read pretty complex examples, but I do not understand **how Backbone models interacts with DOM selectors?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Backbone.js models shouldn't interact with the view layer at all.

Views on the other hand should represent model changes in the view, but Backbone.js does not have any built-in support for DOM-manipulation, templating, CSS, etc.:

> **Backbone is agnostic with respect to your preferred method of HTML templating**. Your render function could even munge together an HTML string, or use `document.createElement` to generate a DOM tree. However, we suggest choosing a nice JavaScript templating library. [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js), [Haml-js](https://github.com/creationix/haml-js), and [Eco](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco) are all fine alternatives. Because [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) is already on the page, [_.template](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) is available, and is an excellent choice if you've already XSS-sanitized your interpolated data.

From [official documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-render).